# Split into list of lists by string with commas and semicolons Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string input like this:

```
1,2000,5,1;1,2050,5,2;2,3000,10,3
```

How can I split it into a list of lists like this:

```
[ [1, 2000, 5, 1], [1, 2050, 5, 2], [2, 3000, 10, 3], ...]
```

I tried regex but kept getting confused between both commas and semicolons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do exactly as you said: split by semicolons and then by commas.

```
s = "1,2000,5,1;1,2050,5,2;2,3000,10,3"
[x.split(',') for x in s.split(';')]
#[['1', '2000', '5', '1'], ['1', '2050', '5', '2'], ['2', '3000', '10', '3']]
```

If you further want lists of numbers, convert the strings to numbers:

```
[list(map(int, x.split(','))) for x in s.split(';')]
#[[1, 2000, 5, 1], [1, 2050, 5, 2], [2, 3000, 10, 3]]
```